# MVC and JQuery Load parameter List

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a JQuery function that load some data from C# and update information on my view.

I must to load a large dataset and all works fine, but for some reason i must to load a dynamic list and elaborate its from JQuery.

The list is "listCasistiche" and when i load it from MVC the JQuery function goes in error.

How can i take this list?

The JQuery function is this:

```
var data = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', rowindex);
            var uf = new FormData();
            uf.append("id", data.Id);
            var url = "/Clienti/LoadSelezionato";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: uf,
                error: function () {
                    // The function go in error
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result != "error") {
                        result.listCasistiche.forEach(function (entry) {
                            alert(entry.IdCasistica);
                        });
                        ricaricaNeri();
                        $('#OwnLead').val(result.ownerLead);
                        $('#dataLead').datepicker('setDate', result.dataLead);
                    }
                }
            });
```

The MVC LoadSelezionato function is this. All other parameters are loaded well:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoadSelezionato(FormCollection form)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(form["id"]);
            try
            {
                Cliente clienteLead = conc.Clientes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
                if (clienteLead != null)
                {
                    var elemento = new
                    {
                        ownerLead = clienteLead.OwnerLead,
                        dataLead = clienteLead.DataLead,
                        listCasistiche = conc.CasisticheClientes.Where(x => x.IdCliente == id).ToList()
                    };

                return Json(elemento, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json("error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json("error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Thanks to all

Comment: What error exactly? Function `error` can take up to three arguments: `jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown`. Also, you can try to get error via browser's console.

Comment: You should console.log(entry) and check your object properties